# Is making a jQuery post request to php script safe using just a token in SESSION to validate?

Tags: php, jquery, security, post

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to do is to make a jQuery POST request from a clicked html element that has an encrypted data attribute uid and sending this encrypted data attribute uid through the jQuery POST request to a getData.php file which decrypts the uid and uses the decrypted uid to query from the database and return json encoded results.

Here is what the .html file would contain:

```
<div data-uid="YshZrKI4qWCHBUnX3vd/Aw==" class="request" style="border:5px solid black;">
    uid is encrypted with AES-128-CBC
</div>
```

This would be the jquery:

```
$('.request').on('click', function() {
        var UID=$(this).data('uid');
        $.post( "pull/data.php", { uid:UID}) // Maybe add a token?
          .done(function(request_data) {
            data = JSON.parse(request_data);
            alert(data);
          });
    });
```

pull/data.php would look something like this:

```
//some kind of verification here? 
if($_SESSION['User']['Token'] == SomeKindOfValidationFunc()) // Would this make it more secure?
    include_once '../databack.php';
    include_once '../keys/request.key.php'; // contains static key and iv
    $key = $evalrequest_key;
    $iv = $evalrequest_iv;

    $id = openssl_decrypt($_POST['uid'], 'AES-128-CBC', $key,0,$iv);
    $results = Get("SELECT * FROM tableX"); //just returns an associative array of results from db

    echo json_encode($results);
```

Is this technique safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: In the sense that not just anyone can use the jquery to pull data from the database.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php